# Logging ssh remote commands to `bash_history`

Tags: bash, sshd

SSH allows a remote user to issue some command without interactively logging in to the server, as the last line of `ssh` usage indicates:

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-Q protocol_feature]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

When ssh is invoked with a remote command, the `.bash_history` file does not get updated (i.e., the remote command is not added to `.bash_history`). I managed to "simulate" this effect by adding the following command to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ForceCommand if [[ -z $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then bash; else printf "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\n" >> .bash_history; bash -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"; fi
```

The above command checks whether the environment variable `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is empty:

- If so, no remote command is issued, and we simply run `bash`.
- Otherwise, `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is added to `.bash_history`, and the remote command within   `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` is executed.

It works as expected, but I need a bit more: I want the current timestamp to be added to  `.bash_history` as well. To this end, I added the following command to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ForceCommand if [[ -z $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then bash; else printf "#`date +%s`\n$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\n" >> .bash_history; bash -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"; fi
```

But when I try to `ssh` to the server, I receive the following error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

If I remove `#` before `date +%s`, it works correctly. But I need `#` to be printed before the timestamp, as it is the correct format for the `.bash_history` file.

Comment: I do not understand the problem but putting a `\ ` before the `#` might help. As the whole command is passed to `bash -c`, `"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"` should be enough as second command.

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Sorry, I still get the same error. Maybe there's another way for escaping `#`, which is possibly commenting out the rest of line?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Using `printf "\x23..."` instead of `printf "#..."` solved the problem. But I'm still eager to know how to escape `#` in the latter command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `#` in `sshd_config` is interpreted as the beginning of a comment and everything following it is ignored. Although (according to `sshd_config(5)`) `""` may be used to quote arguments containing spaces, they do not quote `#`.

That also explains the error you get. `sshd` only passes the following to `bash`:

```
if [[ -z $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then bash; else printf "
```

The second `"` cannot be found as the command line ends just after the first one.

To prevent this behaviour the literal `#` must not be used:

- As `printf` is used here anyway, using its capabilities to use backslash-escaped characters comes in handy. `#` can be written as `\x23` (hexadecimal), `\43` (octal), `\u23` (Unicode, hexadecimal up to 4 hex digits) or even `\U23` (Unicode, hexadecimal up to 8 hex digits). The same works for `echo -e`. Note that the `\` has to be quoted, so use either `"\43"`, `'\43'` or `\\43`.
- In cases where you do not need `echo` or `printf`, you can get `bash` (works on `zsh`, too) to do the replacement by using `$'string'`. For example: to do `touch foo#bar`, you could write `touch $'foo\x23bar'`. If the value has less than the maximum amount of allowed digits (3 for octal, 2 for hexadecimal and 4 or 8 respectively for Unicode) you should use leading zeroes to avoid misinterpretations. For example: `$'foo\u23bar'` evaluates to `foo⎺r` while `$'foo\u0023bar'` gives the expected `foo#bar`.
- Avoid using `#` (literal or otherwise) alltogether by putting all functionality into a script and then just put `ForceCommand /path/to/script` in your configuration.

The second option also allows you to forgo `printf` by using the format option of `date` more extensively. Instead of

```
printf "\x23`date +%s`\n$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\n" >> .bash_history
```

You can write

```
date $'+\x23%s'"${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND//%/%%}" >> .bash_history
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said in a comment above, "I'm still eager to know how to escape `#`." I used `printf "\x23..."` instead of `printf "#..."`, and it worked. But is there another way for escaping `#`?

Comment: @SadeqDousti I included a few ways to escape/avoid `#` in my answer. There are probably many more, but I think I covered the most practical ones.